# sublime text VS os terminal

Tags: bash, python-2.7, sublimetext3, macos-high-sierra

I am an absolute beginner using (actually trying to) Mac High Sierra with Sublime3 and Python2.7. Just installed them.
When I test Sublime on terminal, here's what I get:

```
pc37:desktop flop$ one
-bash: one: command not found
```

I setup Sublime to write in Python and saved the file "one.py" on my desktop.
Does it come from Sublime or the OS?
I read a few debugging articles on the subject but didn't understand half of it... Didn't want to make the situation worst using wrong command lines.
Could someone help please? Thank you! Flo

Answer (score 2):

You need to use valid `Bash` command syntax for executing `Python` scripts in Terminal:

```
python one.py
```

...or...

```
./one.py
```

Of course this requires you `cd` to `~/Desktop` first.

Comment: Thank you I'L'I !

Comment: I get a 'permission denied' with the second one. Is something still wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @florentpierre: The second command should work similarly; you could try to change the permissions on the script - `chmod +x one.py` then try the command `./one.py`. If this solved your issue please click/tap the checkmark at the top left of the answer — cheers!